# Regex to replace matches but also ignore when matches within quotes

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, stringr

Trying to match and replace "and" or "or" to "&" and "|" when it occurs outside of quotes except when they occur within quotes.

Quotes could be single(') or double(").

The string is as follows:

```
Industry ='Education' or Industry =\"Energy\" or Industry = 'Financial or Bank' or Industry = 'Hospitality' or Industry = \"Food and Beverage\"  and Industry = 'Utilities'
```

Expected output:

```
Industry ='Education' | Industry =\"Energy\" | Industry = 'Financial or Bank' | Industry = 'Hospitality' | Industry = \"Food and Beverage\"  & Industry = 'Utilities'
```

I know that we might have to use lookarounds but cant figure out how. I am using stringr package in R for all my regex manipulations.

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data.  In some places, you have double quotes, some have single quotes.  Not clear

Comment: How are literal `'` and `"` escaped inside the quoted strings?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew have added the escapes for double quotes within the string

Comment: @akrun New to the stackoverflow's formatting. Sorry about the formatting. I understand that dput is a function in R, but how is that relevant in this case.

Comment: Because by copying your string from your post I get some errors.  Looks like you escaped it now.  But, before it was not the case

Comment: @akrun Oh I understand your concern now. Fixed it. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider an approach to match double- and single-quoted substrings to omit them and only process `and` or `or` in all other contexts. The easiest way is to use `gsubfn` where you may pass a PCRE regex that will do exactly that:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> x <- "Industry ='Education' or Industry =\"Energy\" or Industry = 'Financial or Bank' or Industry = 'Hospitality' or Industry = \"Food and Beverage\"  and Industry = 'Utilities'"
> pat = "(?:\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b(and|or)\\b"
> gsubfn(pat, ~ ifelse(z=="or","|", "&"), x, backref=0, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Industry ='Education' | Industry =\"Energy\" | Industry = 'Financial or Bank' | Industry = 'Hospitality' | Industry = \"Food and Beverage\"  & Industry = 'Utilities'"
```

The `(?:\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b(and|or)\\b` pattern will match:

- `(?:` - an alternation group:

  - `\"[^\"]*\"` - a double quoted substring having no double quotes inside
  - `|` - or
  - `'[^']*'` - a single quoted substring
- `)` - end of the group
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - discard the match, proceed looking for the next match
- `|` - or
- `\\b(and|or)\\b` - Group 1: either an `and` or `or` as a whole word.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Moqc6/1).

Depending on how the literal `"` and `'` are escaped inside `"..."` and `'...'` you will need to adjust the `(?:\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')` part of the regex.

The `~ ifelse(z=="or","|", "&")` part is a callback function that receives the only argument (named `z` inside this function) and its contents are the match value you get from the regex (i.e. either `or` or `and`). If the match value is equal to `or`, the match is substituted with `|`, else, with `&`.

Comment: Could you please explain the use of ifelse within the gsubfn function, the documentation around this function is not very helpful.

Comment: @DeepakSadulla Please see the update. By the way, just FYI: you may add `ignore.case=TRUE` to the `gsubfn` call and use `ifelse(tolower(z)=="or","|", "&")` to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Understood. Appreciate it :)

Comment: This would also work::  `gsubfn(pat, list(or = "|", and = "&"), x, backref=0, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

this is an ugly way to do it, but it's working for your specific case:

For Or :

```
(?:'|")(?:.*?)(?:'|")(?:.*?)(or)(?:.*?)
```

For And :

```
(?:'|")(?:.*?)(?:'|")(?:.*?)(and)(?:.*?)
```

i recommend using https://regex101.com/ to help build and test your regex

Answer (score 0):

Your question has potential problems, because nested content may not be handled well or at all by a single regex.  That being said, if we assume that the `or` values you want to replace by pipes always occur *after* a quoted string, then we can try the following:

```
gsub("([\"'])\\s*or", "\\1 |", input)
[1] "Industry ='Education' | Industry =\"Energy\" | Industry = 'Financial or Bank' |
Industry = 'Hospitality' | Industry = \"Food and Beverage\"  and Industry = 'Utilities'"
```

By inspection, the `or` values occurring inside quoted strings are surrounded on both sides by unquoted words.  Obviously, this may break down upon seeing other data, or more nested content.

### Demo